# I can't update my Ubuntu!

Tags: update-manager

After upgrading to kernel `3.2.0-31-generic-pae`, my Ubuntu machine is unable to take updates and shows some errors. Also, the update-notifier stays in my tray.

[image: When i click install updates it gives this error]

[image: And sometimes this error message also pops up]

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f`
but it gave me the following output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for balakrish: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lcdproc-extra-drivers libg15render1 libsdl-gfx1.2-4 libsvga1 libsdl-net1.2
  libxosd2 libmikmod2 libzeitgeist0.8-cil libtaoframework-sdl1.2-cil
  libg15daemon-client1 libsdl-mixer1.2 libtaoframework-opengl3.0-cil lcdproc
  libnunit2.5-cil libsmpeg0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,958 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 513139 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic_3.2.0-31.50_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic_3.2.0-31.50_i386.deb (--unpack):
 error creating directory `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic/include/config/comedi/usb': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae_3.2.0-31.50_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae_3.2.0-31.50_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae/include/config/comedi/addi/apci/3001.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae/include/config/comedi/addi/apci/3001.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic_3.2.0-31.50_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae_3.2.0-31.50_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`df` gives this output:

```
balakrish@balaKrish:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda15       35G  3.0G   30G  10% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           766M  876K  765M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  356K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda16       25G   20G  3.5G  86% /home
/dev/sda14      6.9G  5.0G  1.7G  76% /usr
/dev/sdb1        74G   31G   40G  44% /media/Miscellaneous
/dev/sda7       120G  119G  1.2G 100% /media/Library
/dev/sda12      100G   31G   70G  31% /media/Songs
```

`sudo fdisk -l` gives this:

```
balakrish@balaKrish:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002f59b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   125837144    62918541    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       125837206  1953503999   913833397    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       125837208   293603939    83883366    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       293604003   461370734    83883366    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       461370798   713028959   125829081    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       713029023   808298602    47634790    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda9       880795818  1132453979   125829081    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda10     1132454043  1227834214    47690086    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda11     1300220838  1447022744    73400953+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda12     1447022808  1656735254   104856223+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda13     1656735318  1953503999   148384341    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda14     1285543936  1300219903     7337984   83  Linux
/dev/sda15      808300544   880795647    36247552   83  Linux
/dev/sda16     1227835392  1279238143    25701376   83  Linux
/dev/sda17     1279240192  1285537791     3148800   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00028680

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   156301487    78150712+  83  Linux
```

`ls /usr/src` output:

```
balakrish@balaKrish:~$ ls /usr/src
linux-headers-3.2.0-24              linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-29
linux-headers-3.2.0-25              linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-30
linux-headers-3.2.0-26              linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic      linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic-pae  linux-headers-3.2.0-31
linux-headers-3.2.0-27              vboxhost-4.1.20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output above notice this:

```
 error creating directory `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic/include/config/comedi/usb': No space left on device

unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae/include/config/comedi/addi/apci/3001.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae/include/config/comedi/addi/apci/3001.h'): No space left on device
```

Then as a result of your `df` :

```
/dev/sda14      6.9G  5.0G  1.7G  76% /usr
```

It means that you have 1.7G free in `/usr`. `linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic` and `linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae` will be installed in the `/usr/src/` directory.

This is your error so you have to clean up in `/usr`.

Try to clean the old kernel images and headers found in `/usr/src`.

Comment: How to clear my /usr directory?

Comment: You dont have to clear you have just to remove uneeded files and directories from. Do you have old kernels headers there?!

Comment: Yes. I have them located there. Just deleting them won't do any problem?

Comment: delete the oldest ones and leave the latter one

Comment: list the `/usr/src/` entries

Comment: I added the information in the original post.

Comment: remove all unless `linux-headers-3.2.0-30` & `linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic` & `linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic-pae` and sure dont delete `vboxhost-4.1.20`

Comment: I deleted all of them except the on you have specified. Do i have to restart? or try installing it again?

Comment: try now `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Wow! I tried installing.. Now it works.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `sudo apt autoremove` . It will remove all old kernel images in  `/usr/src/ `

Answer (score 2):

Here is the secret:

> No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk
>   full error.

So, the solution is to free up some disk space first!

You can do this in many ways:

1. first I would try to clean up the apt's cache with: `sudo apt-get clean`,
2. after that to clear the browser's cache if the `/home/` directory is not on separate partition,
3. also delete the thumbnail cache with `rm -rf ~/.thumbnails`,
4. eventually to check and delete the old log files in `/var/log/` directory.

These are painless disk freeing tricks.

### * Update

If none of these helped you then you probably ran out of inodes, so you should recreate your FS with more inodes, or try to keep the partition clean.

Comment: But i have 31.0 GB free on my disk.

Comment: Can you post your output for: `sudo fdisk -l` and `df`?

Comment: @idiot Why did you delete your comment? Please put this information into *your original post*, please.

Comment: @Frantique i edited my post and pasted the information which you asked.

Comment: Do the apt's clean first, reboot, and let's see, what happens.

Comment: @Frantique still the same problem..

Comment: Okay, let's see if the partition is error free. Issue: `sudo touch /usr/.forcefsck`, and reboot.

Comment: @Frantique I did, but still the same problem persists.

Comment: Ok, let's see this: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: 'You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic but it is not installed
 linux-headers-generic-pae : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5989/discussion-between-frantique-and-idiot)

Comment: is there any way to roll back to the previous version of my kernel and use that? 
i used previous versions options in GRUB menu. but the problem persists in the previous version too. So if there is a way to uninstall the new kernel and use the previous one, please direct me.

Answer (score 0):

To get best of both answers simply use -

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
```

To remove old kernels in /usr/src/ -

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

and clean apt cache -

```
sudo apt-get clean
```