# apt-get: No space left on device (12.04)

Tags: apt, dpkg, disk-usage

I have read every thread I could find -- even the ones that say that the question has been answered elsewhere but none of them address the specific issue I am having.  Update Manager ran and produced errors relating to unmet dependency and  suggested using **apt-get install -f** which fails with this message:

```
Unpacking linux-headers-3.5.0-36 (from .../linux-headers-3.5.0-36_3.5.0-36.57~precise1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.5.0-36_3.5.0-36.57~precise1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-36/arch/arm/mach-iop32x/include/mach/glantank.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-36/arch/arm/mach-iop32x/include/mach/glantank.h'): No space left on device
```

I suspect that the last 5 words **No space left on device** are significant but df and du both show adequate space. So I am wondering, what device needs more space?

Ouput from `df -h`

```
Filesystem 
Size Used Avail Use% 
Mounted on /dev/sda1 5.5G 4.4G 786M 86% 
/ udev 996M 4.0K 996M 1% 
/dev tmpfs 402M 880K 401M 1% 
/run none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock none 1004M 156K 1004M 1% 
/run/shm /dev/sdb1 30G 1.4G 27G 5% 
/home /dev/sdc1 299G 31G 268G 11% /media/HD-PCTU2
```

Comment: Do you have space on the root partition?

Comment: Please paste (i) the output of `df -h`and (ii) the output of `mount`. dpkg will clean up the files after it finished working, so it might appear that you have enough space when in fact you don't. Consider running `apt-get clean` before you start dpkg.

Comment: to  monitor do `watch -n 1 df -h` in a terminal while doing the `apt-get install` (it will slow down a bit you i/o but you will know which file system is too small)

Comment: Problem occurring also with Ubuntu 14.04 and kernel version 3.13.0.108 in one computer out of three. I started off with http://askubuntu.com/questions/223143/broken-package-after-update-linux-headers-error-brokencount-0 but the answers shown here are in the same line.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space

Answer (score 52):

I just encountered this same problem.  I elsewhere came across a mention of inodes, and ran in my terminal to check inode usage :

```
  df -i
```

This showed inode use at 99%.  So, while my disk had plenty of space left, I wasn't able to create more files because of the limit in the number of inodes.  Some disk cleanup was the solution to my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem caused by kernel updates which do not remove old kernels automatically. Linux headers of every kernel update occupy a considerable number of inodes! --- My "safe" solution was to move two kernel headers directories to a different filesystem: `cd /usr/src ; cp -a linux-headers-3.2.0-3{2,3}* /home/tmp-hdr ; rm -r linux-headers-3.2.0-3{2,3}*`, `apt-get-install -f`, remove some other headers the right way: `apt-get purge linux-headers-...`, move the headers from the tmp back: `cd /usr/src ; cp -a /home/tmp-hdr/* .`. Remove more of the old kernels using `apt-get purge`.

Comment: Please consider participating on the bug reports with low activity: Bug #1089195 [linux-headers will eat your inodes on LTS.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1089195), Bug #690911 [Installation without formatting fails to remove old kernels](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/690911)

Comment: @pabouk I wonder, if you could have used `dpkg --purge linux-headers-3.2.0-3{2,3}*; apt-get -f install` so that no copying was needed?

Comment: @jarno It was a long time about but I think that all the commands using the dpkg or apt database were failing. I think it was because of broken dependencies and other inconsistencies caused by insufficient number of inodes during an automatic upgrade.

Comment: The required disk cleanup could be done by `sudo linux-purge --fix` once the [script](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38300038-feature-request-the-command-should-work-like-this) is published.

Comment: How do you remove packages since `dpkg` won't work because of no space left? I think only pabouk's solution (manually `mv` `cp` etc) is possible

Comment: pabouk's solution does work: `dpkg --purge <pkg>` does remove straight away, even if there is no space left on the device.

Answer (score 48):

I'm thinking your boot partition is full of old kernel images, leaving no room for the new one `apt-get` is trying to install. You can type

```
dpkg -l linux-headers-\* linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
```

into a terminal window. When I do this, I get

```
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-18                    3.8.0-18.28                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-18-generic            3.8.0-18.28                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-19                    3.8.0-19.30                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic            3.8.0-19.30                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-21                    3.8.0-21.32                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-21-generic            3.8.0-21.32                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-22                    3.8.0-22.33                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-22-generic            3.8.0-22.33                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-23                    3.8.0-23.34                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-23-generic            3.8.0-23.34                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-25                    3.8.0-25.37                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-25-generic            3.8.0-25.37                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                     3.8.0.25.43                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

Since I have quite a few, I could delete some of the oldest with

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.8.0-18
```

If `apt-get` fails because it misses some package dependencies (which you can't install due to the lack of free inodes), you can resort to `dpkg` directly instead:

```
sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-3.8.0-18
```

Do that a couple of times to your oldest `linux-headers-*` and you should have room.

Comment: This brings to light the other issue.  Every time I attempt to run dpkg it tells me that it has an unmet dependency     The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.5.0-36-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.5.0-36 but it is not going to be installed       and that is the thing that won't install because there isn't enough space

Comment: Perhaps a backup of your user files is in order, before you mess with your boot partition? I've never had trouble doing this, but if I did, I'd have everything I needed for a reinstall. Of course, I do a backup every day anyway.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need to mess with the boot partition and that there was a way to break out of the endless cycle  of dependency.  I see now that it's probably going to be easier to backup data and start over.  Now that I know the importance of cleaning out older items I'll make it a habit.  Thanks to all for their assistance.

Comment: Not at all . . . backing up is always a good idea, and you're not really messing with the boot partition very much, just uninstalling some packages with apt-get. It should be a piece of cake. I just suggested backing up your data because I always suggest backing up data if you're having a problem (or even if you're not!) I actually ran those commands on my own system to test them. It took me three minutes to remove `linux-headers-3.8.0-18`.

Comment: If it fails again for `sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-3.8.0-18`, remove `sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-3.8.0-18-generic` and it will take the other header with it.

Comment: you can't use `dpkg` if no space is left

Answer (score 21):

I used `sudo apt-get autoremove` and it removed a bunch of old kernel-headers packages.  Good to go after that.

Comment: In my case apt-get refused to do autoremove giving precedence to the fact that there was a broken package to sort out. Which broken package had been caused by the inode saturation. See also [this AskUbuntu thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223143/)

Comment: Well, this just saved me! After an update my x session was never entering, just asking to log in again and I oft got the no space left message. I thought I had to format my hd, but your  trick just saved me :)

Comment: Lol I can't run this because I have too many files...

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know the limit of the inodes in Linux ext* file systems is around 4 billion, but not less, which is huge amount of files. So your problem is that something is generating a lot of files.
I can propose you to check first this:
http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/10/08/understanding-disk-inodes
So you will find what is filling the inodes of your FS.
I can propose also to clean the apt cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Other solutions all gave me unsufficient space error. Surprizingly after clean I can get some space. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you ran out of disk space, `apt-get clean` / `apt-get autoclean` doesn't give you enough space, and you have some RAM to spare, try my answer at:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726355/250404

I used a ramdisk to squeeze out enough space to complete `apt --fix-broken install` and recover from this.