# "No space left on device" while installing packages

Tags: apt, software-installation

My software center stops updating my software and I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic but it is not installed
linux-headers-generic-pae : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae but it is not installed
```

so I tried apt-get and -f install to no avail with this message:

```
(Reading database ... 652236 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic_3.2.0-57.87_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic_3.2.0-57.87_i386.deb (--unpack):
unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic/include/config/comedi/dt2811.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic/include/config/comedi/dt2811.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg deb:error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae_3.2.0-57.87_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae_3.2.0-57.87_i386.deb (--unpack):
unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae/include/config/net/sch/atm.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae/include/config/net/sch/atm.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic_3.2.0-57.87_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae_3.2.0-57.87_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried going onto software center to see if it could fix it for me and it returned similar messages. Any help for a newcomer?

Comment: It is rather a duplicate of this one: [apt-get: No space left on device (12.04)](http://askubuntu.com/q/317763/67132)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the log

```
...No space left on device No apport report written because the error
message indicates a disk full error...
```

So check your disk space by

```
df -h
```

Or open file explorer (`nautilus`) to check.
Empty your trash, delete unused files and run update and install -f again.

Check the number of free inodes by

```
df -i
```

Comment: Check also free inodes: `df -i`. The same message `No space left on device` is written when the system is out of inodes. Which is a common problem on Ubuntu running for a long time because every kernel update consumes a considerable number of inodes.

Comment: This is an excellent tip @pabouk.