# Free space issue Ubuntu 14.04 not loging in after update

Tags: 14.04, kernel, disk-usage, inode

I have updated my desktop pc to kernel 4.4.0-38 from 4.4.0-36 (that was ok).
After restart I couldn't log in into my computer anymore.

With advanced from grub, i selected the old 4.4.0-36 kernel and tried to delete the new one 4.4.0-38.

Details of the bug mentioned above. When trying to delete kernel with:

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic
> ```

=>

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-38 but it is not going to be installed 
> E: Unmet dependencies.
> ```

or

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
> ```

=>

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-38 but it is not going to be installed 
> linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
> linux-image-generic-lts-xenial : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unmet dependencies.
> ```

and

> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```

WON'T resolve it.

I found this question [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading) and used it to free up space on my ubuntu partition.

As a temporary fix I used this [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry/216420) to set the default kernel as 4.4.0-36 in order to use the computer.

Comment: The standard kernel for 14.04 is 3.13.0-96-generic, at this time (at least in 64-bit, which is what I run).  What makes you think 4.4.0-38-generic will work with 14.04?  The fact other 4.4.* kernels will work doesn't mean newer builds are compatible...

Comment: Don't remove the new kernel. Instead have a look at [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version). After that it should be much easier to isolate and fix the issue with the newer kernel.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Hi.The system upgraded to 4.4.0-38, i just  accepted the update. Anyway Ubuntu is no longer serviced for older than 4. Kernels in 14.04  LTS.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi. What I explained above is done in  an older kernel(4.4.0-36).In 38 I can't log in.

Comment: @ZeissIkon 14.04 is on topic. Users have every right to use a different kernel, that doesn't make their question off topic.

Comment: @DavidFoerster When I enter the password and hit enter the screen refreshes and I'm asked to input the password again in 4.4.0-38. Also I have an error (in 4.4.0-36) Error:BrokenCount>0 . Regarding syslog: there are only records from today 30.09.2016

Comment: @DavidFoerster Regarding auth.log there are results from 26.09.2016 only and from the folder lightdm  which one? I have lightdm.log, lightdm.log.old, x-0.log,  x-0.log.old, x-0-greeter.log, x-0-greeter.log.old?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Syslog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23256496/ . auth.log.1: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23256502/ . auth.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23256508/ The auth.log.1 has the recordings from before the update to 4.4.0-38 kernel.

Comment: @DavidFoerster after a new failed try to login into 4.4.0-38 kernel syslog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23256591/  auth.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23256597/

Comment: @DavidFoerster I tried to log in as user and as guest with no luck.  Yes I can log in in a virtual terminal in 36 and 38  kernel.

Comment: @DavidFoerster No one has a clue how to solve this problem? Am I the only one affected by this? I can't install anything in Ubuntu... the bug I mentioned in my question above about the 4.4.0-38 kernel is incomplete... Is reinstaling Ubuntu the only solution to this?

Comment: Since you have ≥20 reputation now, let's continue this discussion [in chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47381).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with David Foerster I read this [apt-get: No space left on device (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04) and I found out about inodes being at 1% free space . You can ckeck this using:

> ```
> df -ih /usr/src
> ```

and my result was:

> ```
> Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
> /dev/sda6        550K  540K   11K   99% /
> ```

Before I ran into this problem, i found this question [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading) and used it to free up space on my ubuntu partition but didn't free up inodes space.
So using the above question [apt-get: No space left on device (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04) I did that and now my problem is solved.

From now on I'll free up space using [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading) and this [apt-get: No space left on device (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04) to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I used Synaptic; searched for 4.4.0-38; marked for removal; apply. After, apparently redundant, not required, I ran "suso update-grub" then rebooted. Just for sanity, after reboot, I ran "sudo apt-get autoremove" then "sudo apt-get clean" then "sudo apt -f install"

I rebooted, again, and all was well, running kernel 3.19.0-69.

Then I ran the system tools - administration - software updater, which started to re-install 4.4.0-68. I cancelled the system update. Still Googling for a permanent fix for not being able to log into 4.4.0-38.

I can't take credit for the following - found them online. I've successfully used them all:

Show all saved versions of kernel - Ubuntu

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
```

Show all kernels and headers that can be removed, excluding the current running kernel - Ubuntu

```
kernelver=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//') dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve $kernelver
```

After upgrading kernels and rebooting to test it, you can remove all other old kernels with: (Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

Comment: Hi. Your second command doesn't work on mine. It says grep: option requires an argument -- 'e'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: Hi.  David Foerster helped me and I'll write(or he will) an answear to this problem. Now I'm loged in 4.4.0-45 kernel and it seems ok.