# Can I remove the 3.13 kernel series from Kubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

Some time ago, I installed the 4.4 kernel series in the form of [the HWE option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831767/why-hasnt-my-kubuntu-14-04-lts-upgraded-to-the-4-4-kernel-series) for Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I did this mainly because the 4.4 series kernel is a little faster than the 3.13 series.  Now, however, I'm still getting updates to both kernel versions, and occasionally, if they don't arrive on the same day, my reboot after the kernel upgrade will start the machine in the 3.13 series kernel.

Is it safe to uninstall the 3.13 kernel series package(s) from Kubuntu 14.04, in order to keep only the 4.4 series?  Is there something special I need to do to prevent this causing problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the kernel packages (image and headers) with the 3.13 version. It is quite safe.

Meta packages `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` will also be removed.

You already have other meta packages (`linux-generic-lts-xenial`, etc) to update the 4.4 kernels.

Comment: Thanks, it's done, and no problems seen (couple days, so far).  Should cut down on updates as well as space filling up.