# No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?

Tags: disk-usage

I've run into a problem on one of my servers running 16.04: there is no disk space left.

I have no idea what is taking up the space. Is there a command to list the current directory sizes, so I can traverse and end up in the directory taking up all the space?

Comment: Check the disk usage analyser

Comment: @PranalNarayan No GUI as it's on my server I'm afraid :(

Comment: Darn you, now I went looking, found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/baobab/+bug/942255 and wish it was a thing.

Comment: wrt "no GUI, is a server": you could install the GUI app (assuming you are happy with it and the support libraries being on a server) and use is on your local screen via X11-tunnelled-through-SSH with something like `export DISPLAY=:0.0; ssh -Y <user>@<server> filelight` (replace `filelight` with your preferred tool). Of course with absolutely no space left, if you don't already have the tool installed you'll need to use something else anyway!

Comment: @DavidSpillett As stated, ***there is no space left on the server***. So I can't install anything.

Comment: @KarlMorrison As I also said in that comment. But I was pointing out that if the server _did_ happen to have the tools and libs present, being a server with no direct GUI access need not be a barrier to using them. Even if the server is not local X remoting over SSH works well for many tools (though some respond rather badly over higher latency links so depending on how remote you and the server are with respect to each other, and the tool in question, YMMV).

Comment: Even if you have no space you could delete something unnecessary and install a tool

Comment: @ViktorMellgren Indeed if you have junk on the server, mine is extremely slim though, which in this case made it a problem. However true as you say, in most cases you could delete something :)

Comment: @KarlMorrison Mind sharing what it turned out to be? :D

Comment: @MarkYisri Indeed I can! The command led me to the directory where Docker keeps it's images. A script I had was creating images which when built were dangling https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/. This lead them to just *exist* as my script removes a certain tag. Run this on a cronjob and walla, none images started taking up space until all space was taken. :)

Comment: Try this on root directory then drill down to directory you want `du -sh * | sort -h`

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Finding what's using all the space in *nix](https://superuser.com/q/12611/241386)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

As always in Linux, there's more than one way to get the job done. However, if you need to do it from CLI, this is my preferred method:

I start by running this as root or with sudo:

```
du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
```

The grep is to limit the returning lines to those which return with values in the Megabyte or Gigabyte range. If your disks are big enough, you could add `|T` as well to include Terabyte amounts. You may get some errors on `/proc`, `/sys`, and/or `/dev` since they are not real files on disk. However, it should still provide valid output for the rest of the directories in root. After you find the biggest ones you can then run the command inside of that directory in order to narrow your way down the culprit. So for example, if `/var` was the biggest you could do it like this next:

```
du -cha --max-depth=1 /var | grep -E "M|G"
```

That should lead you to the problem children!

**Additional Considerations**

While the above command will certainly do the trick, I had some constructive criticism in the comments below that pointed out some things you could also include.

1. The `grep` I provided could result in the occasional "K" value being returned if the name of the directory or file has a capital G or M. If you absolutely don't want any of the K valued directories showing up you'd want to up your regex game to be more creative and complex. e.g. `grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[MG]"`
2. If you know which drive is the issue and it has other mounted drives on top of it that you don't want to waste time including in your search, you could add the `-x` flag to your `du` command. Man page description of that flag:

   ```
     -x, --one-file-system
         skip directories on different file systems
   ```
3. You can sort the output of the `du` command so that the highest value is at the bottom. Just append this to the end of the command: `| sort -h`

Comment: This is exactly what I do.

Comment: Your grep returns any folders with the letters M or G in their names too, a creative regex should hit numbers with an optional dot+M|G, maybe `"^[0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*[MG]"`

Comment: If you know it's one drive that's the issue, you can use the `-x` option to make `du` stay on that one drive (provided on the command-line). You can also pipe through `sort -h` to correctly sort the megabyte/gigabyte human-readable values. I would usually leave off the `--max-depth` option and just search the entire drive this way, sorting appropriately to get the biggest things at the bottom.

Comment: @Muzer, why mess with `-x`? for this? Just give the mount point of the drive as the argument to `du`.

Comment: @alexis My experience is that I sometimes end up with other rubbish mounted below the mountpoint in which I'm interested (especially if that is `/`), and using `-x` gives me a guarantee I won't be miscounting things. If your `/` is full and you have a separately-mounted `/home` or whatever, using `-x` is pretty much a necessity to get rid of the irrelevant stuff. So I find it's just easier to use it all the time, just in case.

Comment: Good point, hadn't thought about `/` in particular...

Comment: Really appreciate the input everyone. :)  @Xen2050 A more creative/complex regex would remove the possibility of folders I'm not trying to include in my output. However, the only other output that I haven't included is those directories with a K amount of data. It really doesn't effect the user if one shows up. And it's much easier to remember a simple and short regex than a long one. (also quicker to write). If you were scripting though and you truly couldn't have K values showing up, then yours would be better.

Comment: @Muzer You make some really good points about how you could further breakdown and organize the disk usage, I'll see about mentioning them in my answer. In regards to removing `--max-depth` I'm not sure I'm totally on-board yet. You force yourself to wait on the system to count disk usage for every directory on the entire system. That's a lot of extra overhead when you could just see for yourself which directory to traverse in a single max-depth and not have to dig down any of the other directories.

Comment: @TopHat Doesn't it already count disk usage for every directory? Or have I misunderstood? Since directory size isn't stored in Linux, it would have to be calculated whether or not you're asking `du` to bother to display it. The only way to calculate it is to add up the sizes for every file and subdirectory, and the only way to calculate those is to add up those sizes, etc.

Comment: @Muzer it has to recalculate values for each directory and file separately when it goes through everything, in order to get the correct total for each directory and file. It only has to do it once for the one directory with a max-depth. That's why if you don't add a max-depth it takes significantly longer for it to return the results.

Comment: You might want to add -xdev to find's options.
This stops it from crossing into other mounted partitions.

Comment: If you have the sort you don't need the grep.

Comment: instead of `du -cha --max-depth=1 /` you can simply use `du -cha /*/`

Comment: this command took my machine 45 years to complete

Comment: if you `sort -hr` it will give you the larger results first, if you like that better. I also do the sort first and then the grep so it still highlights the "G" or the "M".

Comment: brilliant.  uncovered 20GB of mysql binary logs

Answer (score 159):

You can use `ncdu` for this. It works very well.

```
sudo apt install ncdu
```

[image]

Comment: I'm kicking myself as I actually normally use this program, however since there is no space left I can't install it haha

Comment: @KarlMorrison i see several possible solutions, just mount it over sshfs on another computer and run ncdu there (assuming you already have an ssh server on it..) - or if you don't have an ssh server on it, you can do the reverse, install ncdu on another server and mount that with sshfs and run ncdu from the mount (assuming you already have sshfs on the server) - or if you don't have either, ... if ncdu is a single script, you can just `curl http://path/to/ncdu | sh` , and it will run in an in-memory IO stdin cache, but that'll require some luck. there's probably a way to make a ram-disk too

Comment: @KarlMorrison or you can boot a live image of Linux and install it in there.

Comment: once installed type `sudo ncdu /` from the command line. `sudo` because if you dont put sudo, it wont report sizes for folders owned by root, and `/` because if you dont type that it will only report recusively down from the folder you're in

Comment: ncdu is a must have for ubuntu users.

Comment: This works like a charm

Comment: Thank you so much! That's it!

Comment: As mentioned above `ncdu` supports a `-x` flag which you'll probably want to pass in order to exclude other mounted filesystems under `/`.

Answer (score 33):

I use this command:

```
sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20
```

Occasionally, I need to run it from the `/` directory, as I've placed something in an odd location.

Comment: Giving you a +1 for it working! However TopHats solution actually read my drive quicker!

Comment: I often find it more useful to do this without the `-d 1` switch (and usually with `less` instead of `head -20`), so that I get a complete recursively enumerated list of all files and directories sorted by the space they consume. That way, if I see a directory taking up a lot of space, I can just scroll down to see if most of the space is actually taken up by some specific file or subdirectory in it. It's a good way to find some unneeded files and directories to delete to free some space: just scroll down until you see something you're sure you don't want to keep, delete it and repeat.

Comment: @KarlMorrison it doesn't read it quicker, it's just that `sort` waits for the output to be completed before beginning output.

Comment: @muru Ah alright. I however get information quicker so that I can begin traversing quicker if that's a better term!

Answer (score 18):

There are already many good answers about ways to find which directories take most of the space. If you have reason to believe that a few large files are the main problem, rather than many small ones, you could use something like:

```
find / -size +10M
```

Comment: nice. so simple!

Answer (score 16):

In case you are also interested in not using a command, here's an app: [Filelight](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/filelight/)

It lets you quickly visualize what's using disk space in any folder.

[image]

Comment: It's a server I SSH into, no GUI.

Comment: @KarlMorrison I think there are ways to run GUI programs over ssh, but that's an idea for later when you've got space to install packages

Comment: @David Oh yeah, I'm trying to get out of that. It used to be necessary on another platform that I used. I'll fix that comment.

Comment: @Karl yes, it's easy if X is already installed on the client: `ssh -X <your host>` and then run your program from the command line

Comment: @MarkYisri the point is that you need to install the program and its dependencies. And the case of Filelight requires at least KDElibs and Qt, which are not really small. See e.g. [this page for filelight Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/filelight), note how many dependencies it has.

Comment: This is the best tool. Most convenient and and right up to the requirement..!!

Answer (score 13):

I don't know Ubuntu and can't check my answer but  post here my answer based on my experience as unix admin long time ago.

1. Find out which filesystem runs out of space

   ```
   df -h
   ```

   will list all filesystem, their size and their free space. You only waste time if you investigate filesystems that have enough space. Assume that the full filesystem is /myfilesystem. check the df output if there are filesystems mounted on subdirs of /myfilesystems. If so, the following speps must be adapted to this situation.
2. Find out how much space is used by the files of this filesystem

   ```
   du -sh /myfilesystem
   ```

   The -x option may be used to guarantee that only the files  that are member of this filesystems are taken into account. Some Unix variants (e.g. Solaris) do not know the -x option for du. Then you have to use some workarounds to find the du of your filesystem.
3. Now check if the du of the visible files is approximately the size of the used space displayed by df. If so, you can start to find the large files/directories  of the /myfilesystem filesystem to clean up.
4. to find the largest subdirectories of a directory /.../dir use

   ```
   du -sk /.../dir/*|sort -n
   ```

   the -k option forces du to output the sie in kilobyte without any unit. This may be the default on some systems. Then you can omit this option. The largest files/subdirectories will be shown at the bottom of the output.
5. If you have found a large file/directory that you don't need anymore you can remove it in an appropriate way. Don't bother about the small directories on the top of the output. It won't solve your problem if you delete them. If you still haven't enough space than you can repeat  step 4 in the larges subdirectories which are displayed at the bottom of the list.

But what happened if the du output is not approximately the available space displayed by df?

If the du output is larger then you have missed a subdirectory where another filesystem is mounted. If the du output is much smaller, then som files are not shown in any directory tha du inspects. There can be different reasons for his phenomena.

6. some processes are using a file that was already deleted. Therefore this files were removed from the directory and du can't see them. But for the filesystem their blocks are still in use until the proceses close the files. You can try to find out the relevant processes (e.g. with lsof)  and force them to close this files (e.g by stopping the application or by killing the processes). Or you simply reboot your machine.
7. there are files in directories that aren't visible anymore because on one of their parent directories another filesystem is mounted. So if you have a file /myfilesysem/subdir/bigfile and now mount another filesystem on /myfilesystem/subdir  then you cannot see this file anymore and

   ```
   du -shx /myfilesystem
   ```

   will report a value that does not contain the size of /myfilesystem/subdir/bigfile. The only way to find out if such files exist is to unmount /myfilesystem/subir and check with

   ```
   ls -la /myfilesystem/subdir
   ```

   if it contains files.
8. There may be special types of filesystems that use/reserve space on a disk that is not visible to the ls command. You need special tools to display this.

Besides this systematic way using the du command there are some other  you can use. So you can use the find command to find files that are larger then some value you supply, you can search for files that larger than some value you supply or that were newly created or have a special name (e.g. *.log, core, *.trc). But you always should do a df as described in 1 so that you work on the right filesystem

Comment: On a busy server you cannot always unmount things. But you can bind mount the upper directory to a temporary location and it will not include the other mounts and will allow access to the hidden files.

Comment: Before systemd I often had mount failures result in filling the / mount with trash. Writing a backup to /mnt/backup without the USB drive connected for example. Now I make sure those job units have mount requirements.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thank you, I never heard of [bind mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/17485) before

Comment: @ZanLynx: Not just on busy servers. Imagine that you have `/tmp` on a separate file system (e. g. a tmpfs) and something created files in `/tmp` before it became a mount point to a different file system. Now these files are sitting in the root file system, shadowed by a mount point and you can't access them without a reboot to recovery mode (which doesn't process `/etc/fstab`) or, like you suggest, a bind-mount.

Answer (score 5):

I often use this one

```
du -sh /*/
```

Then if I find some big folders I'll switch to it and do further investigation

```
cd big_dir
du -sh */
```

If needed you can also make it sort automatically with

```
du -s /*/ | sort -n
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove the unused files if you haven't done so

Comment: Already did that before :( But good idea for others!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer - but an addendum.

You're hard out of space and can't install ncdu from @erman 's answer.

Some suggestions

- `sudo apt clean all` to delete packages you have already downloaded. SAFE
- `sudo rm -f /var/log/*gz` purge log files older than a week or two - will not delete newer/current logs. MOSTLY SAFE
- `sudo lsof | grep deleted` list all open files, but filter down to the ones which have been deleted from disk. FAIRLY SAFE
- `sudo rm /tmp/*` delete some temp files - if something's using them you could upset a process. NOT REALLY THAT SAFE

That `lsof one may return lines like this:

```
server456 ~ $ lsof | grep deleted
init          1          root    9r      REG              253,0  10406312       3104 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgro                        ups (deleted)
salt-mini  4532          root    0r      REG              253,0        17     393614 /tmp/sh-thd-1492991421                         (deleted)
```

Can't do much for the init line, but the second line suggest salt-minion has a file open which was deleted, and the disk blocks will be returned once all the file handles are closed by a service restart.

Other common suspects here would include syslog / rsyslog / syslog-ng, squid, apache, or any process your server runs which is "heavy ".

Answer (score 2):

I find particularly valuable the output of tools like Filelight, but, as in your case, on servers normally there's no GUI installed, but the `du` command is always available.

What I normally do is:

- write the `du` output to a file (`du / > du_output.txt`);
- copy the file on my machine;
- use [`DuFS`](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/dufs) to "mount" the `du` output in a temporary directory; `DuFS` uses FUSE to create a virtual filesystem (= no files are actually created, it's all fake) according to the `du` output;
- run Filelight or another GUI tool on this temporary directory.

Disclaimer: I wrote `dufs` - exactly because I often have to find out what hogs disk space on headless machines.

Comment: You could just sort -n du_output.txt

Comment: I find the graphical display of the used space way more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

For myself it is important to remove the directory `/mnt` from the calculations (and save time too). Because my `/mnt` contains other partitions without exclusion the result is:

```
$time sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 /
  (... SNIP ...)

du: cannot access '/proc/27561/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/27561/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
270G    /
270G    total

real    2m21.540s
```

With `/mnt` exclusion and suppressing error messages:

```
$time sudo du -cha --max-depth=1  --exclude=/mnt / 2>/dev/null
  (... SNIP ...)

13M     /sbin
1.8M    /run
26G     /
26G     total

real    0m25.019s
```

- `2>/dev/null` sends error messages to the bit-bucket.
- 2 minutes is saved by excluding 246G of Windows and other Ubuntu distributions.
- Accurate `/` total of 26 GB is now displayed.
- Other users may need to exclude `/media` or `/run/user/1000` directories.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder you want to check, and use:

`` for i in `echo *`; do echo $i && du -sh $i; done; ``,

the command prints the file name and the size it takes on the disk in a readable format.

If you want to check folders only, replace `'echo *'` with `'echo */'`.

Answer (score 0):

No programs needed, just find to search for files bigger than 50M and sort them by size.

> find / -size +50M -type f -exec du -h {} ; | sort -h

Answer (score -1):

Similar to @TopHat, but filters some files if they have M, G, or T in the name. I don't believe it will miss size in the first column, but it won't match the filename unless you name files creatively.

```
du -chad 1 . | grep -E '[0-9]M[[:blank:]]|[0-9]G[[:blank:]]|[0-9]T[[:blank:]]'
```

Command line switches explained [here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=du%20-chad%201%20.%20%7C%20grep%20-E%20%27%5B0-9%5DM%5B%5B%3Ablank%3A%5D%5D%7C%5B0-9%5DG%5B%5B%3Ablank%3A%5D%5D%7C%5B0-9%5DT%5B%5B%3Ablank%3A%5D%5D%27) since I didn't know what the c or a did.