# Downloads folder is showing empty

Tags: hard-drive, files

the downloads folder is showing empty, although only 380 gb space is free on system. which means that data in downloads is not accidently deleted.all other folders in home comprised of only 11 gb. the problem is there after turning on computer. even in gparted it shows that 480 gb space is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

Answer (score 0):

Baobab is a usefull tool to see where you have some space used.
If you can't find it by yourself please add a screenshot of your baobab to your question.

[image: Screenshot from baobab]