# Amazon EC2 - xvda1 is 100% full?

Tags: 16.04, server, disk-usage, log

My site size is 25GB & Server Space (Ubuntu 16.04) is 25GB, /dev/xda1 shows 19M free, but still it shows xvda1 is 100% full. Any Fix?

[`df -h` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMbDU.jpg)

Comment: The general solution to your general question is: Delete some data… Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: xvda1 has only 19MB, that's considered 'full' for the most part.  You should delete the stuff that's taking up space.

Comment: Close voters. Answered.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One reason that the filesystem may be showing full when there is space remaining is [space reserved for root.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) Once you've [determined what is taking up all the space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space/911967) You'll need to free some space up or [resize the instance.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

More sources:
https://serverfault.com/questions/330532/xvda1-is-100-full-what-is-it-how-to-fix