# Upgrade from Ubuntu Studio 16.04 to 18.10 errored out with "no space left on disk", and now cannot launch any file manager

Tags: upgrade, mass-storage

This is not a simple disk space problem. I've started an upgrade of Ubuntu Studio 16.04 to 18.10, though ran into "no space left on disk" and it terminated with an error. I no longer can launch Thunar or Nemo to free up space as I get a "symbol lookup error" for each. df shows my drive has 0% available. Is there a way for me to recover from this and restart or resume the upgrade?

Update: I tried "sudo apt-get install -f" though that resulted in a "relocation error". I ran "dpkg --configure -a" and that mostly ran smoothly, though there were a number of dependencies that could not be resolved and were left unconfigured. The building of the initial module for 4.4.0-142 lowlatency succeeded. However, when attempting to generate /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-lowlatency, "Errors were encountered while processing" and there was a list of about 30 packages that followed.

"sudo apt-get install -f" no longer runs as apt-get is unrecognized

"dpkg --configure -a" quickly resolves to the errors it ended with before.

"apt dist-upgrade" also fails with relocation error

"do-release-upgrade" exits with "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading"

In the end, started all over, wiped the partitions and loaded Ubuntu Studio 18.04, and pulled in my backed up files with Back in Time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

Comment: This is not a duplication, as it involves an upgrade operation. Thanks to the link above, I have freed up about 51G of files (using sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20, and then rm'ing large file directories that I already have backed up ) and an unused image using sudo dpkg [image name].

Can I restart the apt dist-upgrade, or do I need to do something else first?

Comment: Ubuntu does not recommend `apt dist-upgrade`. That's Debian. Ubuntu uses `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Should I reboot and try do-release-upgrade, or try it from the command line now?

Comment: Does the file manager work now?

Comment: No, still the same error

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/346795/167115 and please report any errors or if this does not work.

Comment: @Will I would advise *against* rebooting as the system might not reboot right now. If you need to press CTRL+ALT+F2 and sign in to open a terminal if you can't open a terminal and then try running: `sudo screen -D -r` and if that doesn't restart the upgrade then run: `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and, if you get an error, you may need to run `sudo apt -f install` and or `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as well and you may need to run some of these commands more than once to fix things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

Comment: I tried "sudo apt-get install -f" though that resulted in a "relocation error". 

I ran "dpkg --configure -a" and that mostly ran smoothly, though there were a number of dependencies that could not be resolved and were left unconfigured.

The building of the initial module for 4.4.0-142 lowlatency succeeded.

However, when attempting to generate /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-lowlatency, 
"Errors were encountered while processing" and there was a list of about 30 packages that followed.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install -f" no longer runs, apt-get is unrecognized

"dpkg --configure -a"  quickly resolves to the errors it ended with before.

"apt dist-upgrade" also fails with relocation error

"do-release-upgrade" exits with "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading"

Any other avenues I can take?

Comment: @user535733 `dist-upgrade` and `do-release-upgrade` are different things entirely. `dist-upgrade` (or the better named, newer equivalent `full-upgrade`) updates packages. `do-release-upgrade` upgrades the system version (e.g. 18.04 to 18.10). You will need to run a `dist-upgrade` occasionally to keep your system up to date. Please see [`man apt`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) and [`man do-release-upgrade`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html).

Comment: @Will If you could [edit] your question to include the exact results of the commands you ran that would be helpful. It's hard to find in the comments. Copy the exact text if possible, although a picture will do if you can't copy the text. Thanks!

Comment: Threw in the towel and rebuilt the machine from the ground up, with the help of the Back in Time backup, transitioning to US 18.04.