# Ran out of space after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04

Tags: disk-usage, 19.10

I hope someone can help me.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and then all of a sudden received notification saying that I ran out of space and there was only like 25mb space left. I looked on the "disks" program and there was more than a 100gb free on the drive.

I used Stacer to clean unused files and apps etc and then restarted the computer and now I can't login?

How do I fix this?

`df -h` output below:

[image: dh -h output]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `df -h` (If you cannot login, use ctrl-alt-f3 to switch to a TTY and login there).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please see above. @pLumo

Comment: Your disk is full. You need to delete some data or move to an external disk. With 864G of data, you should be able to find something ... Then run `sudo apt install -f` from the TTY. Regarding Stacer.... it seems a nice tool if you know what you're doing. But if you don't, it can lead to serious problems ("cannot login anymore", etc.). Use with caution.

Comment: Is it normal though because I had plenty of space before upgrading to 19.10?

Comment: 100gb should be more than enough, but as we have no output from how it was before it is difficult to tell what has happened

Comment: Fair enough but how can I easily access the hard drive and move data to another drive? I have a 2TB plugged in there as a backup so if I can move some data there, that will be good. Can I use a live CD?

Comment: All good figured out, thanks for your help mate.

Comment: I managed to clear some space but the I noticed on system monitor that I was loosing MBs by the second and please note that this happened after upgrading to 19.10. There was no issues upgrading it completed successfully.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space