# Is it safe to delete folders from /tmp in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage, tmp

I have a `ubuntu` in which disk is getting full. When I checked the disk usage, I noticed that most of the disk was getting used in `/tmp` folder. When I opened the `/tmp` folder, I realized, it has folders created with name `rust_mozprofile2oIotz`  and `Temp-fecb01ff-12cd-47bc-8617-882a1256e` and there were around 4k folders. And below are the contents of it:

[image]

What should I do with these. I am not sure if we  can delete them or not. I need to free up some space. Thanks

Comment: `/tmp` is NOT impacting your disk space - it is a `tmpfs` type system - it exists in RAM for the most part, and is erased automatically on reboots.  It is **not unusual** to see lots of items in `/tmp` but it is *not* the cause of your disk space being lost.  Check the output of `mount | grep /tmp` to see and verify that `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` - your output will look like this:  `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=10485760k)`

Comment: @ThomasWard I think the machine was not rebooted/powered down from last many days (not sure about this). I rebooted it just now and I can see the space is automatically cleared. Also when I run the command `mount | grep /tmp`. It doesnt showed me anything

Comment: `/tmp` is by default not tmpfs in Ubuntu. But it gets emptied after each reboot.

Comment: might be you (or any software you have installed) uses selenium + geckodriver ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719015/geckodriver-is-creating-rust-mozprofile-directories-when-i-use-selenium-webdrive/49817725

Comment: "I need to free up some space"   /tmp/ is not going to get you a lot of free space PLUS it will fill up again in no time. Look elsewhere if you need to free up space. Start with `/var/log/` and see if you can delete old logs and if those logs are rotated.

Comment: @SAndrew Please verify that it is indeed `/tmp` that is eating up your disk space and add the information to your question, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space

Comment: Please explain where you are in need of space. Maybe the output of `df -h` could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, `/tmp` is cleared automatically on reboot. If you plan to keep your computer running for long time (several days) without reboot, it may be reasonable to install `tmpreaper` package. It will automatically clean your `/tmp` directory from files that haven't been used longer than a preconfigured time.