# Space issues on Ubuntu, no space to install GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

My Ubuntu stopped saving my files last time I was working on it, saying "insufficient hard disk space". I tried rebooting my PC and it won't open. Rather, a black screen with a single dash appears. I understand that some drivers may be corrupted and would have to be reinstalled from the root shell, but I have no space.

I know how to resize or increase partitions on Ubuntu, but I don't have GParted either, through which this is done. When I try to install it from the root shell, it gives me the same space error.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

Comment: You have to use gparted, so cannot use it to modify your installed system. Only other drives. For your system then, use Ubuntu live installler which includes gparted (you may still need to unmount swap) to edit your system. Only use Windows tools on NTFS partitions and reboot, so it can run chkdsk which it needs if NTFS size changed.

Comment: If i can somehow manage to recover ubuntu,and install Gparted,how easy would it get to increase the size of the partition?