# AWS EC2 intance service and ubuntu Memory issue/problem

Tags: ram, development, aws

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlBxu.png)I am using AWS EC2 intance service and ubuntu. I am using t2.micro EC2 instance. The EBS volume size is 8Gb. I came accross following problems:

1- I openned my ubuntu console and it showed that the usage memory got 99.8% filled for aws server. I haven't even uploaded anything to the server and the usage memory got to 99.8% of 7.69 GB. I am using 8 GB memory service.

2- There is one folder "/dev" which is 133 GBs. I checked its size in properties it showed that it is 133 GBs. If it is possible can someone explain that how it is taking 133GB in memory but I am using 8 GB service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you are confusing *storage* and *memory*. the 133 GB is *storage* space, aka space on a hard drive. the 8 GB is *memory*, aka space on RAM.

Comment: Please be more specific: What is the AWS EC2 instance type you are using? What is / are the size of the EBS volumes (=disks) you are using? Please log in to your Ubuntu server and run `free` and `lsblk` commands. Please, [edit] your original question to add this info **properly formatted**.

Comment: @FedKad I am using t2.micro EC2 instance. The EBS volume size is 8Gb.

Comment: Memory consumption seems quite normal: less than 50% of memory is used. However, your disk (8GB) is almost full. You should narrow down the directory which is consuming the most disk storage by using the `du` command. Some info that may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space