# My root partition filled up to 21,2 GB after installing Ubuntu 22.04, updating, installing drivers, chrome, and removing snap

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, root, disk

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04, done update, installed NVIDIA and Bluetooth driver, installed Chrome, and removed snap, that's all.

But, when I opened the *+ Other Locations* section in Files and saw my root partition (Computer), I noticed that 21.2 GB out of the total capacity of 65.2 GB had been used. This is the screenshot of my root (`/`) directory *Properties* (I separate root (`/`) and home (`/home`) in a different partition):

[image: root directory properties]

What made my root partition filled up to 21,2 GB with just minor changes after installing? What should I do? Or, is it normal?

Comment: The recommend minimum size for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*in fact all releases since and including Ubuntu 17.10*) is 25GB, so your disk usage is still below the recommend minimum.  Our own usage will dictate what size we need; I'm a user who adds many apps (ie. *bloats* my system down with software) thus I need more than 25GB.  It's not just the *apps* themselves, but app package format that influences the disk space required. Many can survive on small systems (*esp. where everything is cloud based*) but don't forget 25GB is the recommended minimum for a Desktop install.

Comment: It surprises me, I expected some 10GB maybe. Try "baobab" - a disk usage imager and report it here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

Comment: @David The screenshot here very much helps visualize the issue. Please don't remove screenshots from posts when they add context or add visual help.

Comment: In Artur link is ncdu which I highly recommend and use. You have to install it. Makes it a lot easier to use du type command.