# df -h shows 2TB external HDD is almost full but the output for 'du' does not add up

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, df, du

The system that I am using has 18.04 (no dual boot). I have a 2TB Seagate external hard drive which I use for taking the backup of my Ph.D. data. I use `rsync -rtvhP` to take backups. Recently during one of my backups, rsync failed and I saw that the storage was full, but my data is nowhere near 2TB. I checked the output of `df -h` and here is the output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
.
.
.
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  1.8T   36G  99% /media/abhishek/Backup Plus
```

which shows that the drive is almost full. But when I run `du -hs` to see which directory is taking so much space, I get the following output

```
451G    Dropbox_backups
128G    Lamarr
230G    NAVEEN
152G    NSM_backup
2.9M    NSM_Nvidia
3.3G    OLD_FILES_OF_LAMARR
849M    Overlap_Ent_spec
3.4G    Paper_backups
818M    PRL_paper2
32G     Projects
256K    $RECYCLE.BIN
27M     Seagates Files
11M     spectral_density_codes
384K    System Volume Information
8.3M    Templates_of_working_codes
93M     Test
3.8G    WokingCode_and_data_ES
```

which does not add up to 1.8TB at all. Some people suggested using `ncdu` which also gives me the same output (shown below)

Results of `ncdu` :

[image: output of ncdu]

I understand that `df` and `du` are not supposed to show values, but I do not know what is taking up the space. I have seen answers where a similar problem occurs in internal HDD and removing log files has helped, but the drive does not have such log files. I have tried removing the `.trash` file as well. This is perplexing. I can shift the data to another drive and format it to fix it, but I want to understand what is happening.

Related information:

1. When I check **properties** of the hard drive, I get[image: Properties of the hard disk]
2. Running the Disk Usage Analyzer on the drive gives the following [image]
3. Output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/181
loop1    7:1    0 283.1M  1 loop /snap/brave/202
loop2    7:2    0  38.3M  1 loop /snap/okular/119
loop3    7:3    0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop4    7:4    0  49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
loop5    7:5    0   2.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/920
loop6    7:6    0   556K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/112
loop7    7:7    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop8    7:8    0 452.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/56
loop9    7:9    0 362.2M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/4593
loop10   7:10   0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1778
loop11   7:11   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop12   7:12   0 437.2M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20/9
loop13   7:13   0 187.7M  1 loop /snap/okular/115
loop14   7:14   0    22M  1 loop /snap/bashtop/504
loop15   7:15   0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1822
loop16   7:16   0   9.7M  1 loop /snap/htop/3605
loop17   7:17   0 446.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/44
loop18   7:18   0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17950
loop19   7:19   0    22M  1 loop /snap/bashtop/502
loop20   7:20   0   476K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/781
loop21   7:21   0     7M  1 loop /snap/tex-match/6
loop22   7:22   0 436.3M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/7
loop23   7:23   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop24   7:24   0  72.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/504
loop25   7:25   0   2.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/178
loop26   7:26   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop27   7:27   0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/741
loop28   7:28   0 272.4M  1 loop /snap/brave/197
loop29   7:29   0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2679
loop30   7:30   0  72.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/509
loop31   7:31   0   9.6M  1 loop /snap/htop/3417
loop32   7:32   0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/884
loop33   7:33   0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2667
loop34   7:34   0   696K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/115
loop35   7:35   0 362.1M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/4578
loop36   7:36   0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop37   7:37   0 323.5M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14
loop38   7:38   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  14.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0 139.7G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0 776.9G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part /media/abhishek/Backup Plus
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

4. The output of `sudo lsof | grep -c deleted`

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1001/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
4624
```

5. Output of `mount | grep 'media'`

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/abhishek/Backup Plus type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1001,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142937/discussion-on-question-by-abhishek-anand-df-h-shows-2tb-external-hdd-is-almost); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

Answer (score 0):

[ncdu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/ncdu.1.html) is a great utility for identifying large files and the folders containing them. It's in the archive, so `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install ncdu` will install it. Simply run it, either while in the directory you wish to examine, or give it a path as a parameter:

```bash
cd /media/abhishek/Backup\ Plus
ncdu
```

```bash
ncdu /media/abhishek/Backup\ Plus
```

It will take a short while to scan files and their sizes. Then it will present a view which you can navigate with the arrow keys. Importantly the largest folders will be at the top, so easy to spot.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: ncdu]

You may need to run it with `sudo` if there are files which aren't owned by your user in there, to be able to see everything. During the scanning phase of `ncdu` you'll see it report if there are files it cannot access, so the use of `sudo` may not be required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed and ran `ncdu` with sudo but the results are the same. I have added the outcome of the command in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of output you show for `du` result i.e.:

```bash
451G    Dropbox_backups
128G    Lamarr
230G    NAVEEN
152G    NSM_backup
2.9M    NSM_Nvidia
3.3G    OLD_FILES_OF_LAMARR
849M    Overlap_Ent_spec
3.4G    Paper_backups
818M    PRL_paper2
32G     Projects
256K    $RECYCLE.BIN
27M     Seagates Files
11M     spectral_density_codes
384K    System Volume Information
8.3M    Templates_of_working_codes
93M     Test
3.8G    WokingCode_and_data_ES
```

Suggests that you are using `du` with a shell glob character/s most probably `*` e.g. like so:

```bash
du -hs *
```

The `-s` option as in [`man du`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/du.1.html):

> -s, --summarize
>
> display **only** a total for each argument

Therefor, unless you pass multiple arguments to it e.g. as a result of the expansion of the shell glob character `*`, it should only output a one line summary e.g. like so:

```bash
size   Directory/File
```

The shell glob character `*` is only expanded to non-hidden directories/files ... So those are not included in `du`'s arguments/output.

To get those accounted for by `du` you need to use `du` with no `*` i.e. like so:

```bash
du -hs
```

for a summary or like so:

```bash
du -ha
```

for details.

It might be worth noting that `df` works on the filesystem blocks level and not Directory/File level like `du` ... So to clarify.

Comment: I ran both `du -hs` and `du -ha` without the shell glob character. Size of the data contained in the mount point i.e. /media/abhishek/Backup \Plus is 1004GB.  But `df -h` shows me 1.8TB is full. I do not know what is taking rest of the space.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand  `df` accounts for deleted files if a process using them is still running while `du` doesn’t … Did you try rebooting then running `df` after rebooting?

Comment: I did check after rebooting the system. I exclusively use this hard drive to store data only. So I doubt any process might be using the deleted files. I also tried deleting the .trash folder but it did not change anything.