# 1TB SSD filled with simple Xubuntu installation - how can I find what is taking so much space?

Tags: kubuntu, hard-drive, files, filesystem

On a recent and relatively vanilla installation of Kubuntu, after having difficulties I realized that it is somehow taking up nearly all of the 1TB drive when little else is installed. It has partitions as follows:

```
1MB /dev/sda1 Grub
513MB /dev/sda2 fat32 EFI Boot
953.37GB /dev/sda3 lvm2 pv Kubuntu
```

For sda3, the KDE Partition Manager shows that only 2% of the space is available as 931.32GB is being used. How can that be possible on a nearly-fresh 22.10 installation? I suspect that the recent upgrade to 23.04 did not complete and failed to clean up after itself but that should not account for such space being taken up.

UPDATE: The space being used and as reported above from the KDE Partition Manager closely matches that reported by GParted. However, Stacer, a third-Marty system manager, shows what is expected that only 55.2GB is being used. How can there be since a discrepancy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

Comment: Thank you, I already looked at that. Since this is a virtually fresh installation, I was looking for something to do with cleaning up what was an apparently-failed installation that did not complete through its own cleanup job. That said, the space being used is what was reported by the KDE Partition Manager and GParted but programs like Stacer show what is expected that 55.2GB is being used. Why such a discrepancy between an included app and a third-party one?

Comment: KDE Partiton Manager doesn't reflect the space on LVs - you're using LVM so partition managers will not show the proper disk usage as the LV (Logical Volume) is assigned all the LVM member partitions' space.  Use `df -h` and share the output as an edit to your post.