# Ubuntu root partition is full, system won't boot, and "sudo apt-get clean" isn't working

Tags: grub2, root, memory-usage, recovery-mode, cleanup

I set up an Ubuntu rig to host Plex and act as a file server on my local network. I'm new to Ubuntu, so I followed directions and things seemed to be running fine--no problems with boot up or memory.
After about two or three weeks, I noticed Plex was running weird, so I decided it was time to run updates and restart the rig.
When I log back in, there's a text box saying memory was low. I find that odd, and figure that's something I can look into if it persists after a restart. I run restart, and start-up gets stuck on a black screen with white text telling me I have some hardware options are turned off in BIOS. After some Googling, I get into Recovery Mode and System Stats show my `/` directory is at 99% capacity (19gb/20gb). I try running "Clean Up" and nothing happens. I opened root and ran `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`. No change. I even tried deleting everything in `/tmp/*`. Still no change. How do I get the root directory small enough that I can boot again?

I realize 20gb is probably too low for the root directory; however, I don't want to resize partitions until I've had the chance to back-up the files on the system. I do have a second hard drive in the system that is untouched (I was planning on setting it up as the back-up drive), I don't know if that could be leveraged to find a solution here.

EDIT: Apologies for not including this info in the original post;
Ubuntu version 23.04. If I understand it correctly, the 4tb hard drive is partitioned into 20gb `/` where it boots from, 100mb swap, and the rest in `/home`.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; is this a server you're talking about? as you 25GB has been the minimum recommended disk space for / since Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop (ie. all releases using GNOME 3 & later). As you add more functionality you'll need more space; or are you talking about a server (no GUI/desktop)? and what release?

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether the whole system is in the same `/` partition, or whether you have separate partitions for /home, /boot, /var and so on. Also when you refer to "memory" do you actually mean disk space, or is there a separate issue with memory usage?

Comment: @steeldriver I added additional information to the OP

Comment: You've add release details; but not said if this is Ubuntu 23.04 Server (*where 20GB will be less of a problem*) or Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop (*where the recommended minimum disk space is 25GB*) You can usually still login to a text terminal even with lack of disk space; otherwise you can use a *live* system to backup data. Each additional app you add needs space in `/` (*with few exceptions; some like *appimage* can provide you to store them elsewhere*) but we still don't know if this is a Server or Desktop install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space) Using `apt clean` and `apt autoremove` is a common mistake -- software packages generally take up little space and are rarely the cause of filled storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)