# sudo apt-get upgrade problem with initramfs and firmware

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

How could I resolve this problem?

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for szymon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  dkms docker-ce-cli fwupd fwupd-signed libegl-mesa0 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin1 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-compute-450:i386
  libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-decode-450:i386 libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-encode-450:i386 libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450
  libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-gl-450:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386 libxatracker2
  linux-modules-nvidia-440-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-driver-450 nvidia-kernel-common-450
  nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-utils-450 ubuntu-advantage-tools xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_49.0.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915
cat: write error: No space left on device
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Is there a question?   I don't see one.    All I see is a *messy* paste for an *unstated* OS & release without any sort of question.   (*FYI: had there been a question, I'd have edited the formatting for you; but even if formatting was corrected - there still is no question*)

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04). If you purge headers, remember not to purge the latest version because that one is still in use. Just remove some of the older ones. Alternatively, it might be easier to run `sudo apt autoremove` to fix the issue instead.

Comment: Looks like the partition with /lib/firmware on is full, use `df` to check.

Comment: Your `/boot` partition is full. [Running `sudo apt autoremove` should solve your problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/212053/8698).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)