# Package system broken / unable to install updates due to incorrect (?) disk full message

Tags: apt, package-management

Here's a copy of part of the output I'm seeing when I try to update;

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-49_3.2.0-49.75_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating directory `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-49/arch/m68k/platform/68EZ328': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-49_3.2.0-49.75_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

```
colin@colin-Satellite-A60:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        11G  8.5G  1.6G  85% /
udev            336M  4.0K  336M   1% /dev
tmpfs           138M  768K  137M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            343M   88K  343M   1% /run/shm
```

I've tried the usual `sudo apt-get install -f` as well as `sudo apt-get clean` without success - I know I've got a lot of old Linux kernels installed which I can't remove because of the disk space full error, so I'm running out ideas, can anyone advise please ?

Note this is xubuntu running on an ancient Toshiba A60 laptop as a WUBI install IIRC :-}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workable solution in reply to someone having the same problem in another thread;

 [Of the two answers, the first worked for me (I'm not really sure what to do with the second answer to be honest !](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223143/broken-package-after-update-linux-headers-error-brokencount-0?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a Wubi install, the Windows filesystem might have ran out of space.

Comment: Sadly, that's not the case - Windows has 8Gb free, and the Wubi virtual file system has 1.5Gb free :-}

Comment: Can anyone think of any other ways of solving this ? (other than a full reinstall)