# Errors when installing 12.10 updates

Tags: 12.10

I run Ubuntu 12.10 when I attempt to install updates I get the following message:

```
ERROR: BrokenCount >0'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem then post the full error report in your question.

Comment: when it says that 27.4 MB additional disk will be used do I answer yes or no?

Comment: click yes that is y

Comment: Installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Comment: plz post the full error report.

Comment: No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error.....Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-44-generic_3.5.0-44.67_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: what was the output of `df -h`?

Comment: plz post its output in the question.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/195014/i-cant-update-my-ubuntu

Comment: Fetched 12.3 MB in 1min 45s (116 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 430556 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.5.0-44-generic (from .../linux-image-3.5.0-44-generic_3.5.0-44.67_i386.deb) ...
Done.

Comment: I'm making progress now! You've been very helpful. Thank you very much!